# Passing byte array between activities android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a byte[] holding a music file to another activity in my app.  But when i do this i get the Failed Binder Error meaning the size of music file is too big (over 2MB).  Then i went ahead and tried to compress it with the method below but that still gave me the error.  How can i get the file under 1MB to pass it through an intent or is there another way to achieve this without using intents?

Compress Code:

```
public static byte[] zipByteArray(byte[] file)
            throws IOException{
        byte[] byReturn = null;
        Deflater oDeflate = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFLATED, false);
        oDeflate.setInput(file);
        oDeflate.finish();
        ByteArrayOutputStream oZipStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            while (! oDeflate.finished() ){
                byte[] byRead = new byte[ZIP_BUFFER_SIZE];
                int iBytesRead = oDeflate.deflate(byRead);
                if (iBytesRead == byRead.length){
                    oZipStream.write(byRead);
                }
                else {
                    oZipStream.write(byRead, 0, iBytesRead);
                }
            }
            oDeflate.end();
            byReturn = oZipStream.toByteArray();
        }
        finally {
            oZipStream.close();
        }
        return byReturn;
    }
```

Comment: *Carefully* use a static data member. By "carefully", I mean make sure that you do not leak 2MB of a `byte[]`.

Comment: I think one other way you can try, write it to disk in activity A and pass the location to activity B, read it again. May not be efficient as in memory read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a file straight through as a parameter to an intent is not a very good idea (or what intents were designed for). Trying to compress it is a band-aid measure that will break if the limit changes or the file itself needs to change to one that would not fit in your compression format.

You should instead create a temporary file (or other temporary storage to which you can refer from an intent), and pass a reference to it through your intent. A static member might work, but you must be very careful that you do not keep the reference around for too long, as then a memory leak could result.

Comment: going to go with creating a temp storage to store and retrieve from, can't believe i didn't think of doing that. Thanks!